# Add my app to AutoStart apps list & running state in android programmatically

Tags: android, background-process, whitelist, autostart, miui

I want my app to be in the autostart list and in running state after installation.

I know when I install an app like (WhatsApp) it goes automatically to the autostart list. I want my app to be the same

[image]

some app always listed under the running state like show above I want my app to be the same

I try this code for autostart

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
     startActivity(intent);'
```

it's work but it will throw to autostart manager where I manually found the app and allow autostart. also, I try a lot but don't get any possible solution for put application into the running state like shown into the image.